# Cant retrieve local records from store using Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to retrieve records which have already been loaded into the store by using this line in a controller:

```
var allProducts = this.store.all('product');
```

However, this is returning a strange object (see screenshot). When I call length on it, the result is "undefined." I have used the Chrome Ember inspector to confirm that records have indeed been loaded into Product before the above line of code is run. I thought since store.all returns a recordarray I could iterate over it immediately unlike a promise. Where am I going wrong please?

[image: Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to iterate over the recordarray using a traditional for loop. Seems that a) recordarray cannot return length and 2) one must use a forEach loop to iterate over it, which is what I had initially did but dropped because forEach does not support break or continue.

Comment: Support for break and continue with `forEach` is easily achievable... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nijebe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

The `strange object` that is returned is a `record array`. This is important so that Ember can set up observers for arrays that are loaded. I believe this is what is causing your confusion. See [more specifics in the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/):

> It's important to note that DS.RecordArray is not a JavaScript array.
>   It is an object that implements Ember.Enumerable. This is important
>   because, for example, if you want to retrieve records by index, the []
>   notation will not work--you'll have to use objectAt(index) instead.

You will have to look at the documention for `DS.RecordArray` but you should be able to iterate over it using the `forEach` method. See the [ember array documentation for more details](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html).

Answer (score -1):

Ahh promises! :)

You should be able to do this:

```
var allProducts = this.store.all('product').then(function(products) {
  return products;
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use a promise. See: "find returns a DS.PromiseArray that fulfills to a DS.RecordArray and *all directly returns a DS.RecordArray.*"